# Total coin supply, how it works, and what the code means?

Tags: bitcoin

I am currently studying the bitcoin and litecoin to try and get a better understanding of cryptocurrencies, and blockchains in general - and I have spotted something in the code that I have a question about.

in src/amount.h - I see the following code...

```
/** No amount larger than this (in satoshi) is valid.
 *
 * Note that this constant is *not* the total money supply, which in Bitcoin
 * currently happens to be less than 21,000,000 BTC for various reasons, but
 * rather a sanity check. As this sanity check is used by consensus-critical
 * validation code, the exact value of the MAX_MONEY constant is consensus
 * critical; in unusual circumstances like a(nother) overflow bug that allowed
 * for the creation of coins out of thin air modification could lead to a fork.
 * */

static const CAmount MAX_MONEY = 84000000 * COIN;
```

Now, the comment here, seems to suggest that this code does not actually define what the total supply of the currency will be, even though the amount of Litecoin available is in fact 84,000,000...

So, my real question :

Is the real total supply held in another piece of code? If so, what am I missing, where can I find this code, and if I were to be trying to edit this (I'm not - but I want to understand what is going on here) - would I need to edit code in multiple places?

NOTE : Tagged bitcoin even though this is litecoin souce in the question, because litecoin doesn't appear to have a stackoverflow tag, and the two codebases are similar anyway.

EDIT : I also wanted to add, that I performed a grep for "84000000" - and only really found that one line of code to be relevant... So I must be missing something...

EDIT 2 : According to literally every coin out there on git that I have looked at - this is the number that they change when adjusting the total supply - so is the comment just wrong - or did I misunderstand it?

Answer (score -1):

I realise this is an old question, but since it hasn't been updated I'll provide an answer.

As the source suggests, MAX_MONEY is simply a sanity check. If someone tries to create a transaction spending 500 million Bitcoin, and it somehow manages to bypass all other sanity checks, the network will still reject it because the amount exceeds MAX_MONEY. So MAX_MONEY is not directly related to total supply, but as you have observed, many alts will set MAX_MONEY to the expected total supply over the lifetime of the coin.

For a pure proof-of-work coin with consistent reward scheme (eg halving every X blocks) the total supply can be pre-calculated, but a future fork could change that.

For a typical proof-of-stake or hybrid proof-of-work and proof-of-stake coin, the maximum supply can be estimated by simulation, but the exact amount will vary depending on network activity.

(This assumes there is not another part of the code that cuts off all rewards after a limit is reached.)